# How can I delete all text on a line after a certain point e.g. the "#" symbol [Notepad++]

Tags: notepad++, edit

I am currently editing down a very large text file (82,000 lines), and need to delete all text beyond the # symbol. Since all the lines are of varying length, I cannot simply use SHIFT + ALT to vertically select lines, so, I was wondering whether there would be a way to do this using one of Notepad++'s features?

Example of some lines:

```
Go. 行きなさい。   #2877272 (CM) & #7421986 (Ninja)
Hi. こんにちは。   #538123 (CM) & #373351 (tommy_san)
Hi. もしもし。    #538123 (CM) & #385517 (mookeee)
Hi. やっほー。    #538123 (CM) & #3480285 (arnab)
```

Comment: You'll want to use a regular expression. `#.*$` should grab everything from literal `#` character until the end of line. Use that in find and replace with regular expression option.

Comment: Thank you for this! Also, would you know a way to quickly and efficiently convert these two lines (The English words and the Japanese translations) into two separate columns in a CSV file?

Comment: I'd use a regex to find a space character which has no English alphabet after it and replace that. `\s(?!.*[a-zA-Z])$` should do the trick if the Japanese is the last thing on the line.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove unwanted text and add a comma between values in a single pass:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([a-z.]+)\h+(\S+).+$`
- Replace with: `$1,$2` or `"$1","$2"` if you want quotes arround each value
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    ([a-z.]+)   # group 1, 1 or more letter or dot
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    (\S+)       # group 2, 1 or more non space character
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1
,       # a comma
$2      # content of group 2
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]